# JQuery split ajax response html problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, split, response

I have an ajax function in *home.php* that give me back this html response from *elaborate.php*

in ***elaborate.php*** i have this summarized situation:

```
if(a<b)
 {echo "yes.";}
else
 {echo "no.";}

echo<<<EO
insert a title...aand something more!
EO;
```

back in ***home.php*** I want to split in two the response I get,cause I need to use each part in different situations.
Let's call it '*response*' I did this:

```
var splitResult=response.split(".",2);  
var yesNo=splitResult[0];  
var article=splitResult[1];
alert(yesNo+article);

if(yesNo=='yes'){/*do something*/}
$(article).appendTo("#myDiv");
```

The problem this and you can simply understand by looking at the ***alert***:

```
yes  
insert a title
/*the alert doesnt show the rest of article var cause the dot:"...and something more!"*/
```

the split function is splitting again even it i put the limit of 2..why??

thanks guys
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`limit` argument for `.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) doesn't say "stop splitting after 2"`, it says "split normally, just give me the first 2 results".

I think what you'll want is this instead:

```
var splitResult=response.split(".");  
var yesNo=splitResult[0];  
var article=splitResult.slice(1).join(".");
alert(yesNo+article);
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/YWQHR/)...though I'd use a different delimiter, for example:

```
var response = "yes|||insert a title...and something more!"
var splitResult=response.split("|||");  
var yesNo=splitResult[0];  
var article=splitResult[1];
alert(yesNo+article);
```

[You can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/YWQHR/2/).